# How to set outputStream in AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking-3

I had an option in older AFNetworking to set outputStream with:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation* requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
requestOperation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:somePath append:NO];
```

How can I achieve this in AFNetworking 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the setDataTaskDidReceiveDataBlock on the AFHTTPSessionManager to write the data to a buffer.  Then write that buffer to a file using the NSOutputStream.

```
NSString *baseURLString = @"https://www.whatever.com";
NSString *pathString = "lol/rofl/";

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]];
manager.responseSerializer = [[AFHTTPResponseSerializer alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

[manager setDataTaskDidReceiveDataBlock:^(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull dataTask, NSData * _Nonnull data) {
    [self.dataBuffer appendBytes:[data bytes] length:data.length];
}];

[manager GET:pathString parameters:nil progress:...]
```

Then refer to this Apple guide to use an NSOutputStream and the stream delegate callback method below to write the data to a file: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/WritingOutputStreams.html

```
 - (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
```